# Can't access to admin page in simplesamlphp on Azure App Service

Tags: php, nginx, azure-web-app-service, nginx-config, simplesamlphp

I'm currently configuring simplesamlphp on my Azure app service.
I installed simplesamlphp to -> `/home/site/wwwroot/simplesamlphp`

I can access to `mysite.azurewebsites/simplesamlphp/public`, which redirect me to `mysite.azurewebsites.net/simplesamlphp/public/module.php/core/welcome`

But if i want to access to **mysite.azurewebsites.net/simplesamlphp/public/admin**, I get an nginx 404 error, and i get redirected to **mysite.azurewebsites.net/simplesamlphp/public/module.php/core/loginuserpass?AuthState=_35ad00934026a834017630e72d95e663c2cdcecda1**

I tried to change the nginx configuration in **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**,
But I feel like it doesn't do much, I can break the file and my site will still be accessible.

FIY : My problem appeared **after **restarting my app service. Before, **I was able** to access my simplesamlphp admin page.

Thank you !

-Change the config.php file
-Try to change nginx.conf several times.
-Try to add the serveur configuration in etc/nginx/sites-available and /sites-enabled

I am expecting access my administration page of simplesamlphp.
There are no tutorial for simplesamlphp on azure.

Comment: Does the user accessing the page has necessary permissions to on that directory.